# PDF for the hypergeometric distribution

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, lua

I wish to plot the p.d.f. for the hypergeometric distribution, and I have been using `lua` combined with `pgfplots`. However I get an error when I use the density function with the formula for the binomial coefficient.

How can I make compatible these two declarations? (with or without Lua; cf. code below). Thansk a lot in advance!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry} % just for this example
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{fontspec,luacode,luatexbase}
\begin{luacode}
   -- 'mchoose' is patterned after the posting in http://stackoverflow.com/a/15302448.
   function mchoose( n, k )
     if (k == 0 or k == n) then
       return 1 
     else 
       return (n * mchoose(n - 1, k - 1)) / k 
     end
   end

   -- print an arbitrary length integer as formatted string
   function fwrite(z) 
      tex.sprint ( string.format("%.0f",z) )
   end

   -- the pdf used for the dist. in lua...
   -- hypergeometric pdf
   --   function hypergeo(n11, n1_, n_1, n)
   --       return math.exp(math.lbinom(n1_, n11) + math.lbinom(n-n1_, n_1-n11) - math.lbinom(n, n_1));
   --   end

\end{luacode}

\newcommand{\mchoose}[2]{%
    \directlua{fwrite ( mchoose ( 
               "\luatexluaescapestring{#1}",
               "\luatexluaescapestring{#2}" ) )
    }}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  no markers, domain=-1:10, samples=100,
  axis lines*=left, xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$f(x)$,
  every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
  every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
  height=5cm, width=12cm,
  enlargelimits=false, clip=false, axis on top,
  ]


\pgfmathdeclarefunction{hyper}{4}{%
  \pgfmathparse{($\mchoose{#3}{#1}$)+($\mchoose{#4-#2}{#3-#1}$)-($\mchoose{#4}{#3}$)}%
% or?
%  \pgfmathparse{(mchoose{#3}{#1})+(mchoose{#4-#2}{#3-#1})-(mchoose{#4}{#3})}%
}

\addplot [very thick,cyan!50!black] {hyper(4, 10, 42, 16)};


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11):

This function can be declared and evaluated directly in PGFPlots, without the need for lua.

You can declare the function for the binomial coefficient using

```
declare function={binomcoeff(\n,\k)=\n!/(\k!*(\n-\k)!);}
```

and then use that in the declaration of the hypergeometric distribution probability mass function:

```
declare function={
    hypergeompmf(\N,\K,\n,\k)=binomcoeff(\K,\k)*binomcoeff(\N-\K, \n-\k)/binomcoeff(\N,\n);
}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={binomcoeff(\n,\k)=\n!/(\k!*(\n-\k)!);},
    declare function={
        hypergeompmf(\N,\K,\n,\k)=binomcoeff(\K,\k)*binomcoeff(\N-\K, \n-\k)/binomcoeff(\N,\n);
    }
]
\begin{axis}[
    samples at={0,...,20},
    ycomb,
    yticklabel style={
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
        /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
        /pgf/number format/precision=2
    },
    every axis legend/.append style={at={(0.5,1.1)}, anchor=south}
]
\addplot [mark=*, cyan] {hypergeompmf(80,25,20,x)}; \addlegendentry{$N=80, K=30, n=25$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and sorry the late reply :). Just a question: For the possibility of getting 4 (of the 16) face cards in hand of 10 over repeated draws from a pack of 52 cards, then N=52, n=10, k=16. But by specifying x (e.g. 4) I get a Uniform distribution...

Comment: @Toño: I'm not sure I understand correctly: Are you plotting `hypergeompmf(52,16,10,4)`? In that case you're getting what looks like a uniform distribution because you're just plotting a fixed value (you might as well just say [`\addplot {0.224};`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=hypergeometric+distribution+with+n%3D10%2C+N%3D52%2C+m%3D16%2C+x%3D4)). To get a more meaningful, you need to have an independent variable, i.e. `x`. Try `\addplot {hypergeompmf(52,16,10,x)};`, for instance.

Comment: That is! Just need to be careful with the legend...