Geometric Distribution Graph
How do I draw a Geometric Distribution Graph on latex? I have searched for a while and I haven't found much. I attached some images of the binomial/normal graph equivalent of what I'd like to make.  [

Welcome to TeX.SE! You should check out the tutorials on https://tikz.dev/, as well as look into the plot syntax. Alternatively, you may use pgfplots, but my preference is pure TikZ because pgfplots makes some decisions for you that I like to customize myself.

it would  be really easy to draw actually, provides you know the formula for the curve.

Welcome to TeX.sx! On this site,
a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I
get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application
(e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this
complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are "too
localized". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a
minimal working example (MWE):
you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Welcome. // When you look to the right, the Related column limks to a pgfplots solution for the (discrete) similar hypergeometric distribution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208117/245790 . Adjust the data or coefficients and there you go. // To learn anout pgfplots see https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/ . Toggle for the Tikz manual.

[edited]
Using the pgfplots package it's quite simple :
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots} % For plotting
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} % Ensures compatibility

\begin{document}

% First plot: Bar chart
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar interval, % Histogram with continuous bars
        bar width=0.2cm, % Reduce bar width
        ymin=0, ymax=0.6, % y-axis limits
        xmin=0.5, xmax=10.5, % x-axis limits
        xlabel={$k$}, % Label for the x-axis
        ylabel={$P(X=k)$}, % Label for the y-axis
        xtick={1,2,...,10}, % Positions of ticks on the x-axis
        title={Geometric Distribution with $p=0.3$}, % Plot title
        grid=none, % Remove grid lines
        every axis/.append style={font=\footnotesize}, % Text style
        legend style={anchor=north east,legend columns=1} % Position the legend inside, aligned to the right
    ]
        % Direct plot of the geometric distribution
        \addplot[
            fill=blue!30,
            draw=blue,
        ] expression[domain=1:10, samples=10] 
        {0.3 * (1-0.3)^(x-1)};
        \addlegendentry{$P(X=k) = p(1-p)^{k-1}$}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{2cm}

% Second plot: Smooth curve
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        domain=1:10, % Domain limits for the x-axis
        samples=50, % Number of samples for the curve
        ymin=0, ymax=0.6, % y-axis limits
        xmin=0.5, xmax=10.5, % x-axis limits
        xlabel={$k$}, % Label for the x-axis
        ylabel={$P(X=k)$}, % Label for the y-axis
        xtick={1,2,...,10}, % Positions of ticks on the x-axis
        title={Geometric Distribution with $p=0.3$}, % Plot title
        grid=none, % Remove grid lines
        every axis/.append style={font=\footnotesize}, % Text style
        legend style={anchor=north east,legend columns=1} % Legend position
    ]
        % Smooth curve for the geometric distribution without points
        \addplot[
            color=blue, % Curve color
            thick, % Increase curve thickness
        ] {0.3 * (1-0.3)^(x-1)};
        \addlegendentry{$P(X=k) = p(1-p)^{k-1}$}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}




Nice. However, the GD is a discrete distribution. Though it’s tempting to draw a continuous curve, it’s discouraged to do so. E.g. P(x=1.5) is quite meaningless. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution // Oh, this also holds for your bar chart … x can be only integer. // Without test, samples=10 might resolve it. Discrete x‘s however are better.

What are you talking about? it is a convention in mathematics. We trace the normal law as a curve while the discrete values ​​have no meaning

About discrete distributions. This „convention“ was wrong at my time, and it certainly still is. After all how do you tell visually a distribution over discrete values (throwing 1 dice) from over continuous data (like measured voltages)? E.g. try throwing a dice 1.4 times …

If you need an other argument: The sum of all probabilities must be 1. In your first diagram, I exceed this sum around k=3, starting leftmost. The area under the continuous curve will be even larger. So this basic condition is simply not met. Doesn’t sound like a good „standard“, does it?

I understand the fact that we are on discrete values ​​and I will rectify the graph with a stick all the units. However, the sum of the areas that I calculate does not exceed 1 for k=3 (contrary to what you say) : 0.5×0.3 + 0.5×0.25 + 0.2×0.5 + 0.18×0.5 + 0.16× 0.5 = 0.545

For the curve, it may be mathematically wrong but it seems to correspond to what he is looking for...

Thank you so much! This is pretty much exactly what I wanted.

You're welcome, if you want you can add +1 to the answer and if you consider the subject closed I invite you to check the answer

@Dorian, same mis-take again, sorry to say. As a discrete distribution, defined only for x in natural numbers, the width are irrelevant, and the bars should be just lines. See this example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208088/pdf-for-the-hypergeometric-distribution/208117#208117

@LuisFonseca, it may be what you looked for, but it's no good idea. See my other comments.

I understand that I was wrong and I greatly appreciate your clarifications on the mathematical concepts, which are a bit complicated for us. However, LaTeX is not a calculation tool, it's a typesetting tool. If he persists in wanting to write and draw something mathematically incorrect, that's his business.
